# Skill cap for Borderlands

Tags: borderlands

I bought the GOTY edition of Borderlands I am a bit confused. I could figure out, that with the included DLC the level cap is now at 69. But what is the **skill cap**?

I have this little tool: http://www.borderlandsthegame.com/skilltree/roland/

It shows me 57 skill points which let me thought, that this tool is not for the latest DLC but for the one where the level cap was 61.

Could someone clear the information for me? I like to know how many skill points I can use.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a total of 105 talents to skill up in.
You start gaining skill points at level 5.

From the [Borderlands wiki](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Skill):

> If the player uses an unmodded character and does not have any DLC, the player will have accumulated 54 skill points by the time they reach the maximum level of 58. However, with the addition of the Mad Moxxi's Underdome Riot, The Secret Armory of General Knoxx DLC, and Claptrap's New Robot Revolution, it is now possible to attain a maximum of 69 skill points (2 extra from The Underdome, another 2 from Claptrap's Revolution, and 11 extra from The Secret Armory).

If you use an editor to change your character, you can actually add 105 skill points and fill up the entire tree.

So to answer your question(s?), 105 is the maximum required to fill up all the trees and 69 skill points is the maximum you can attain from the GOTY edition.

Comment: Isn't 106 needed to fill everything? 35 per skill tree plus the very first one. And can I play with an edited character online, too?

Comment: @WarrenFaith You can use an edited character online. Gearbox started checking for modded guns a while ago but I don't think they've done anything about characters.

Comment: @warrenFaith yep thats a given though, since you can't start spending points until your level 5 so, 105 from there on out :)